# IIS Failing to register

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have IIS Version 7.5 installed on my machine.
But when I am trying to register it using aspnet_regiis.exe -i(-ir) commands then the following error occurs:

Finished installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.17929).
Setup has detected some errors during the operation. For details, please read the setup log file C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\ASPNETSetup_00018.log

Steps Followed:
1. Installed VS 2012 First and then installed IIS.
2. Replaced applicationhost.config file from other machine where IIS was working with my file under folder C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config, but still not worked out.
3. Replaced the path in  of applicationhost.config file with the absolute path but then also it didn't worked out.
4. Uninstalled IIS, VS2012 and then re-installed VS2012 and IIS, but then also success wasn't there.

Please help me to get out of this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Step 1 you used the wrong order. Step 2 is completely wrong.

Comment: I tried the reverse order also, but it didn't worked still.
For step 2, I read somewhere and it was just a hit n trial.

Comment: @Lex Li...now, my IIS has been registered successfully using aspnet_regiis.exe command, but I am not able to browse a aspx page from IIS. Can you please help.